# Owner drawing a checkbox List View

Tags: c++, winforms, winapi, wtl

I have created a List view control with View = Icon / List, with LVS_EX_CHECKBOXES enabled.
And the checkboxes overlap with the items text, so I am wondering how could I create a owner drawn list view with checkboxes ?
I have seen that one has to process LVN_ITEMCHANGED notitication to test if an item has been checked.
How does this apply when the checkbox itself gets owner drawn, how do I approach this problem.
How Do I manage the events, the checkbox checking and unchecking while drawing my own, do I have to implement the checking routines myself or do I get something from the window? A message or something? While drawing my own checkbox how do I differentiate between a click on the item and a click on the checkbox, do I have to check the coordinates of the cursor when the click occured? how do I do this.
THis is with view= icon, it shows ok with view=list

[image]

Comment: `LVS_EX_CHECKBOXES` should not cause the labels to overlap the checkboxes. Could you provide a screenshot to show what you're seeing?

Comment: either way I need to draw it myself, because it has to look different, the question is: if I set it a checkbox style and I owner draw it, DO I have to implement the check/uncheck mechanism myself? By that I mean: do I have to look for where the click has triggered and see if if I hit the area where I would Draw the checkbox? Is this how it is done? How would you proceed if you 'd had to do this (Making a custom designed list with your own styled checkboxes, all items checkboxes and I would prefer it to be Icon/List(View) )

Comment: And so sad that nobody answers this..

Comment: What version of Windows are you running on? I'm pretty sure the latest versions of the current control don't have that bug. Anyway to answer your question, you won't need to handle the mouse activity yourself - the clue is in the name owner **draw**.

Comment: You don't have to owner (custom) draw just for check boxes. It's unclear what can be wrong and what you are actually doing.